# Is "might well" equal to "might as well"? Is one "that" not enough for an object-clause? Are they two other old-fashioned ways?

Tags: grammar, objects

> “Many speakers to the House the other night in the debate on the reduction of armaments seemed to show a most lamentable ignorance of the conditions under which the British Empire maintains its existence. When Mr Balfour replied to the allegations that the Roman Empire sank under the weight of its military obligations, he said that this was ‘wholly unhistorical.’ He **might well** have added **that** the Roman power was at its zenith when every citizen acknowledged his liability to fight for the State, but **that** it began to decline as soon as this obligation was no longer recognized.”— Pall Mall Gazette, 15th May 1906.

William Marriott cited the British newspaper "Pall Mall Gazette" as a note to Machiavelli's "The Prince" (Chapter XIII).

1 It seems to me that "might well" functions as "might as well". Learning from the previous questions, I guess "might well" is another out-of-date usage. Am I right?

2 The whole part following the first "that" (in bold), I think, is the object of "might well have added". Therefore, the second "that" (in bold) should be deleted (at least when it were expressed today), shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, *might well* and *might as well* are two different idioms with different meanings.

*He might well have added* is neutral or approving of what the speaker said, and suggests a way that he might have made it better. The literal meaning is "He might have added ..., and it would have been 'well' (i.e. good) if he had done so".

*He might as well have added* is mildly disapproving of what the speaker said, and sarcastically suggests something that would be even worse. The literal meaning is something like "It would have been just as good (i.e., not very) if he had added ...".

The second *that* is optional, as you suggest; but in my view it is clearer with it than without it. Without it, the reader might be puzzled as to where "it began to decline..." fits in the sentence.

Comment: When not in subjunctive mood, does "might as well" still hint disapproval?

Comment: Good question, @ZhangJian. No, it doesn't, necessarily. It can do, but the tone of voice will different. _Since I'm going into town anyway, I might as well pick up your things  from the cleaners_ is neutral. But _So I've got to redo that work? I might as well just throw it in the bin!_ is frustrated and certainly disapproving.